# Cassandra PHP: "All connections on all I/O threads are busy" after adding node

Tags: php, nginx, cassandra, cassandra-2.2

I am facing a strange problem with cassandra connection, after I added new cassandra node.

**Situation before adding node**:

- 1 cassandra node on server 1 in data center 1
- Fully operational java applications distributed over many machines
- PHP nginx web server on server 1 in data center 1
- Fully operational PHP application (for displaying results)

Then I added second storage server in data center 2. Both storage servers have replication factor 1 (all data are on both servers). Thus I altered keyspaces. Consequently, data have been synchronized smoothly and their validity has been checked via Datastax Devcenter app.

**Situation after adding node**:

- 1 cassandra node on server 1 in data center 1
- 1 cassandra node on server 2 in data center 2
- Fully operational java applications distributed over many machines
- PHP nginx web server on server 1 in data center 1
- PHP application crashes with exception: `All connections on all I/O threads are busy` ..even if there are all connections available.

**What I tried next**:

- I downloaded [Github Datastax PHP code sample](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver#user-content-quick-start)
- If I ran this piece from code via console php command, it worked
- If I ran same code in browser through nginx, i received again `All connections on all I/O threads are busy`

I haven't changed anything in nginx configuration, or PHP webapp. I just changed keyspaces and synced servers.

Any idea how to get rid of that "connections busy" error?